# Пробел при переходе на следующую строку

Tags: пробелы

Бывают случаи, когда в каких-то документах, например, доверенности предложение продолжается на следующей строке при том, что на незаконченной строке в конце нету даже никакого знака препинания.

*Нужно ли в таком случае ставить пробел после последнего слова на незавершённой строке?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Пробел*, который пользователь ставит после последнего слова на незаконченной строке, превращается в *переход на следующую строку*, если последующее слово не вмещается в эту строку.  То есть если его стереть, то это последнее слово склеится с  первым словом на следующей строке.
Если изменить размер шрифта, то будет видно, как *переход на следующую строку* превращается в *пробел*, а *пробел между другим словами* превращается в *переход на следующую строку* в другом месте.
Короче, еще один пробел не нужен.

Comment: "...если последующее слово не вмещается в эту строку". В том то и дело, что вмещается, просто строку ***специально раньше*** переносят. Делят текст по смыслу что ли в рамках этой специфики.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, давайте посмотрим с другой стороны. Что изменится, если вставить пробел? Текст будет выглядеть точно так же. Разве что обрезанный текст выравнивается по центру, тогда из-за пробела в конце будет выглядеть неровно отцентрированным. То есть пробел не может улучшить, а может только ухудшить.

Comment: Да я и не спорю. Мне тоже кажется, что пробел не нужен. Просто я хотел уточнить насчёт того, что строка короткой получается.

Comment: Так они специально разрывают строку, чтобы визуально выделить текст. Короткая строка как раз здесь помогает.